# Why asymmetric weights of RBM can be learned although the network is symmetry?

Tags: neural-network, rbm, deep-learning

I tried to implement the Restricted Boltzmann Machine to confirm the utility of the deep learning method. 
I implemented a RBM and fed the MNIST character recognition data for one layer reconstruction.

But the learned weights of edges were same for each hidden nodes.

then I got wondered why the RBM can obtain asymmetric filters from the symmetric network topology. I couldn't grasp the situation from mathematical formula on thesis around RBMs.

Give me an intuitive insight for this.

Comment: How have you initialized weights?